# MQTT broker (Mosquito) disconnecting after 5 secs

Tags: mqtt

I'm trying to connect with MQTT broker but whenever I am sending the connect packet after 5 secs it is getting disconnected.
Controll packet for connect= {0x10, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x04, MQTT, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x3C},

I'm sending it through AT commands to ESP8266 using UART.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information here

Comment: Please read the doc on asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask